# Werid behviour of cmd + tab on Mac OSX after upgrade to El Capitan

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan

I have this weird problem, i often use cmd+tab to switch between opened applications. After upgrading my OS to El Capitan it started to behave weird. Sometimes it doesn't switch to last focused window but it switches to last application visible on that bar which is displayed after pressing this shortcut. It really freaks me out. Please help.

To explain this problem better i've recorded a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R6gKsCTLt00 when this bug occurs i stop for a while and point my cursor on the application item on that bar.

I have to mention than all this time i'm using cmd+tab only, without shift pressed.

Comment: Ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Droppy ok did it, please continue here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/210095/werid-behviour-of-cmd-tab-on-mac-osx-after-upgrade-to-el-capitan